# Matrix decomposition to its original product

Tags: matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

If I have a squared symmetric matrix $X(m,m)$ which is a result of the product:
$X =Y^T A Y$, in which $Y(n,m)$; and $A(n,n)$ is a diagonal matrix.

My question is:
Is it possible to get the original $Y$ and $A$ matrices from $X$?

Comment: Consider the case where $A=cI,$ $c$ a constant, and the case where $A$ has distinct diagonal entries.This should help quantify the lack of uniqueness in the problem.

Comment: I edited your question to properly $\LaTeX$ify it; I also changed $t(Y)$ to $Y^T$, I hope that is correct?  Feel free to change it back if I was wrong, or let me know.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Robert, you made correct changes